# Indexed PNG file blank when opening in GIMP. CHanging from Indexed to RGB has no effect

Tags: gimp, png, color-indexing

I'm trying to open a silouette file and add to a figure I made in GIMP. GIMP opens up a blank transparent background. I tried changing the mode from Indexed to RGB, but it's still blank. I tried exporting it just to see but then the new file is also blank.

The file is available from: http://phylopic.org/image/c345a923-3481-4472-aab2-6ebe5d28c889/

Comment: The linked file looks perfect - I copied it to the clipboard in the browser and pasted to GIMP as a new file. See it  https://i.stack.imgur.com/deGpF.png  (the red paint is inserted because the license doesn't allow me to distribute the image) What's the exact non-functional step in your case?

Comment: ok weird, I copied and pasted it to a new layer and it works fine. But when I download the image and open it, the file is blank in GIMP.

Comment: The file worked as well when downloaded  as when copied&pasted to GIMP. I guess your download procedure is customized somehow. I opened the original version in the browser, right clicked "Save image as..."  and the resulted PNG worked ok.

Comment: There's something weird with that file. Photoshop opens it as an RGB image (not Indexed), when downloaded from that site, but GIMP opens it as a blank fully transparent image in Indexed mode. However when copying the image from the browser (right click > copy) and opening in GIMP using File > Create > from clipboard, it opens as an RGB image.

Comment: Downloaded file (512x159 px, 9400 bytes, SHA1: 8154f6aa8a1887c4a4e3d5a001e17d187aafbc07) looks OK in Gimp,  Gwenview, Okular, and Firefox. And it's a regular 8-bit/channel PNG, not a color-indexed one (exported to indexed it is 2520 bytes).